# Invalid cast in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I've been thrown an invalid cast exception using LINQ to SQL. Here's my class in C#:

```
[Table(Name = "tbl_request$")]
public class request
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public float requestID;
    [Column]
    public string moduleCode;
    [Column]
    public float park;
    [Column]
    public string requestedRoom;
    [Column]
    public float week;
    [Column]
    public float day;
    [Column]
    public float period;
    [Column]
    public float status;
    [Column]
    public float semester;
    [Column]
    public float priority;
    [Column]
    public float adhoc;
    [Column]
    public float numStudents;
    [Column]
    public float collectionID;
    [Column]
    public float roomCount;
}
```

The database table this corresponds to

```
requestID   float   Unchecked
moduleCode  nvarchar(255)   Checked
park    float   Checked
requestedRoom   nvarchar(255)   Checked
week    float   Checked
day float   Checked
period  float   Checked
status  float   Checked
semester    float   Checked
priority    float   Checked
adhoc   float   Checked
numStudents float   Checked
collectionID    float   Checked
roomCount   float   Checked
```

Everything looks fine to me. Any other suggestions?

```
Specified cast is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Source Error: 

Line 12:             var bookingtable = Database.DatabaseContext.GetTable<Database.request>();
Line 13:             var dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.List<Database.request>>();
Line 14:             foreach (var request in bookingtable)
Line 15:             {
Line 16:                 if (dict[(int)request.collectionID] == null)
```

The stack trace is deep inside LINQ internals.

Comment: @Daniel: Unfortunately, "Invalid Cast" genuinely is pretty much all it says. I'll edit with it

Comment: Check in InnerException what object is wrongly casted.

Comment: Create the model class for that table via the designer and try with that. If it still fails, you've probably hit a limitation with Linq-to-Sql. Otherwise, there is an error in your mapping, which you can find by comparing your class to the one created in the <somename>.designer.cs file.

Comment: @Pawel: There is no InnerException. @skarmats: How do you create model classes with the designer?

Comment: @DeadMG: To clarify, add a "LINQ to SQL classes" item to your project and drag and drop the table from the Server Explorer onto the open designer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that C# wanted a `double?` instead of a `float?`, even though the DB type was `FLOAT`.

Comment: `float?` should work as well, although it is better to use `double?`. In your case, you probably just forgot the ?-part, which means the field in the database can be NULL

Comment: Btw, I recommend you always use the visual designer to create your model classes. It might seem clunky, but it saves you from lots of hard-to-track errors - especially, if you move on to more advanced topics like associations. Just define your foreign keys on the tables and by simply drag-and-dropping, you'll have the correct associations in the code. And if you want to add custom behavior to the designer classes, just put these additions in a separate class file and make the class `partial`. Search for the keywords Linq-to-Sql, partial class and you'll find instructions

Comment: A reminder: a float in SQL server *can* be a 4-byte storage size, in which case a c# float (32 bit) would probably work.  However, a SQL server float with a specified Numeric Precision >24 will result in an 8-byte storage size, which will error unless you use a double (64 bit) in your c# code.  I just ran into the same issue and it had nothing to do with forgetting the Nullable indicator.